# Is it possible to develop windows phone 7 application on windows 8 with visual studio 2012

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I recently upgraded from windows 7 to windows 8.1. Now I need to update my windows phone 7 application. Is there a way to develop WP7 apps on windows 8 with visual studio 2012.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your use case, just install the Windows Phone SDK.

Comment: There is no windows phone 7 SDK for windows 8. There is one WP7.1.1 SDK but it is not supported by VS 2012.

Comment: sorry, I meant WP8 SDK, it also contains stuff for WP7. I am in the same situation, using VS2012 on Win 8.1

Answer (score 2):

No problem. Just download Windows Phone 8 SDK and it will include the earlier stuff for WP7, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pb. You have to install VS2012 and the sdk of wp8 then the sdk of wp7.1.
Good luck ;)